# Is it possible to push the app to background and reopen it while doing integration test in flutter

Tags: flutter, testing

I am testing a package that expires users' session when the app is pushed to the background for some time. I want to write integration test for same, but i couldn't find any way of pushing the app to background and reopening it in docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the FlutterForegroundTask plugin for that (working for me)

```
FlutterForegroundTask.minimizeApp();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));//making sure the app minimized
FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));//making sure the app resumed
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
```